# What does this sequence of Cantor-like sets converge to?

Tags: real-analysis

I have a sequence of sets

$$E_1 = \{0,1/3\}$$
$$E_2 = \{0,1/3,1/9,1/9+1/3\}$$
$$E_3 = \{0,1/3,1/9,1/9+1/3,1/27,1/27+1/9,1/27+1/3,1/27+1/9+1/3\}$$

In general, the set $E_n$ contains all numbers in $[0,1]$ whose ternary expansion has at most $n$ digits and where none of these digits is equal to two.

Is there a set $E = \lim_{n \to \infty} E_n$. I'm aware that if I restricted the digits to not be equal to 1, this sequence would converge to the Cantor set. What happens if I restrict the digits to not be equal to 2?

Comment: This does not converge to the Cantor set because all of these sets are finite. The set you describe will be countable.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. That doesn't seem right. In particular, if $E_n$ is the set of numbers in $[0,1]$ with $n$-digit binary expansions, then each $E_n$ is finite, but the sequence $E_n$ converges to all of $[0,1]$ as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: That's not true as most real numbers don't have finite binary expansions. I guess it depends what you mean by "converges to" though. I'm talking about the union of all $E_n$.

Comment: The set described at the end (numbers with finite ternary representations w/o 1) gives the endpoints of the open intervals removed in the "usual" construction of the ternary Cantor set.  This is a countable set whose closure is the usual Cantor set.

Comment: @Asterix $E_n \subseteq \Bbb Q ~\forall n \in \Bbb N$, so $\cup E_n$ must be countable.

Comment: What is the limit of some (countably many) sets (by definition)? If by chance the limit is the union, what should be shown for this union?